# Is there a way to "SELECT and TRUNCATE" without losing new data?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, truncate

I have an application that writes raw log files to a table called `new` in a PostgreSQL database -- lots of rows and lots of duplicate data. Via a cron job running every minute, I normalize the raw data and insert the normalized results into a table called `summary`, after which I truncate the `new` table.

The normalization is done all via SQL, but I realize that it may take **some** time do execute the SQL statement, during which time additional data may get inserted into the `new` table. This leads me to believe that said additional data inserted while the SQL statement is running may get lost when the table is truncated.

Not knowing exactly how PostgreSQL (or any other SQL-compliant database) handles access to tables when SQL statements are being executed, I'm not exactly sure what to do to ensure no data is lost. Is there a way to "move" all the data in the `new` table into a temporary table and perform the normalization on the data in the temporary table, leaving the `new` table empty until new data gets inserted (which will likely happen during the normalization of the data in the temporary table)? Perhaps there's additional/better approaches to this problem, perhaps using transaction blocks?

---- EDIT ----

It never fails... every time I write up a question on Stack Exchange, it gets me to think about the question in different ways and thus leads me to new terms to search for on Google. Happened this time too. As a result, is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578705/451664) a potential solution for what I'm wanting to do here? Is it the best solution, given it's now quite dated?

Comment: Yes, that solution will work.  The interesting part will be the performance.  How many rows do you process (per minute, for example)?

Comment: @dezso perhaps a couple thousand rows per minute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than one possibility here.

One is what Peter Eisentraut suggested in the post you linked, using a writable CTE which deletes the rows from the table which will be processed or inserted elsewhere *in the same query*.

This approach may be viable with small datasets.  However, there are chances that some table bloat will occur with time, or concurrent inserts and deletes clash on the disk I/O level.

Another way to solve this is using transaction blocks, as you also suggested.  If there are open transactions (that do the inserts, for example) on `new`, the `TRUNCATE` command will wait until these are closed, then it will remove everything.  This means that the problem you anticipate really exists :)

Consider the following:

```
BEGIN;

LOCK new; -- takes an exclusive lock

INSERT INTO staging_table SELECT * FROM new;

TRUNCATE new;

COMMIT;
```

In this case, the exclusive lock will make all concurrent `INSERT` statements wait until the `COMMIT`.  As the `INSERT` in this block should be relatively fast, the waiting time won't be terribly long, while your existing data is safely moved to an other table.  Then comes the `TRUNCATE`, finally the `COMMIT` will release the lock and the waiting inserts can be done.

This way you can move the data processing from `new` to the newly introduced table.

Answer (score 0):

This Truncate process held highest level lock on tables, so no other query can run on the table in parallel with the truncate.

So, if You do :

`truncate table a`

and after that, You do :

`insert into table a values (....)`

What happen in the postgres is : insert will run only after truncate finish. So no new data will get lost. And in contrary, if You `insert` first then `truncate`, `truncate` will run only after the `insert` finish.

Hope it helps

Comment: Before a truncate, I'm going to do a select on the table to normalize the current data in the table and insert it into a different table. My worry is, in between doing the SELECT and the TRUNCATE, new data will be inserted into the table, which will not be captured by the SELECT and will subsequently be deleted by the TRUNCATE, meaning it's lost.

Comment: Maybe You should make `lock table`, `select` and `truncate` in one transaction, making no other insert on the table allowed. Meaning no data lost. But inserted data will have to wait for these processes to complete.

Comment: Looks like you and dezso came up with the same solution at about the same time... thanks!